# How to make custom menu open in new tab

Tags: php, wordpress

how to make a custom menu in dashboard admin that I created to open a new page in the browser.

this is the sourcode that I use

```
add_menu_page(
        'Import Resi', // Page Title
        'Import Resi', // Menu Title
        'manage_options', // Capabiliy
        'import_php/index.php', // Menu_slug
        '', // function
        '', // icon_url
        6   // position
    );
```

Comment: Please post your code here, not an image of the source.

Comment: Hi @BenM im sorry about that. thank's